# Placing Graph vertexLabels into the vertexes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, style

The `DiscreteMarkovProcess` defined in Mathematica can be passed to `Graph` to visualize it. It is exactly what I have done.

```
Graph[hmm];
```

[image]

Which is almost fine except that I want to put characters from "A" to "U" instead of numbers from 1 to 21 inside the vertexes. I tried using

```
Graph[hmm, VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[21]->CharacterRange["A","U"]]]
```

This outputs [image]

I want the letters back into the center of vertexes, According to documentation I can use `Placed`, however doing

```
Graph[hmm, VertexLabels -> Placed[Thread[Range[21]->CharacterRange["A","U"]]],Center]
```

outputs 
[image]

How can I Fix this?

Additional Data:

You can create hmm using

```
p= Table[1/21//N,{21}];
tm = Table[If[j == i + 2, 0.9, If[j == i + 1, 0.1, 0]], {i, 1, 21}, {j, 1, 21}];
hmm = DiscreteMarkovProcess[p,tm];
```

Comment: `Graph[hmm, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Thread[Range[
     21] -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "U"])]]` is your after?Could I vote to colse it as a mistake?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see now the that the issue was that Placed is not Listable? Then why would something like `VertexLables->Placed["Name",Center]` work? Also how could I understand the black thingines inside the graph of my version? I'd appreciate it if you post explanations to those questions as well as your solution as an asnwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graph[hmm,
  VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[]][[i]], Center], {i, 21}],
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding",
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
VertexReplace[Graph[hmm, GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}],
 Thread[Range@21 -> CharacterRange["A", "U"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]